# PostgreSQL 9.5 pg_hba.conf corrupt

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We have a PostgreSQL 9.5 installed on the system and sometimes the postgres service can't be started. When I look into the pg_log I see the following messages:

```
2017-02-07 12:55:18 IST [4800]: [3-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  configuration file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf" contains no entries
2017-02-07 12:55:18 IST [4800]: [4-1] user=,db=,app=,client= FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

After looking into the pg_hba.conf file I can see that the whole file is corrupt. When I open the file in the Windows editor I can't see anything except spaces and when I open it in Notepad++ there are only "NUL" characters in the whole file.

To fix this we copied a fresh version of the file to its location and after that the service starts without any problem. But how can this happen and what can we do to avoid it.

Comment: As far as I know, Postgres _never_ writes to `pg_hba.conf`. I'm guessing the problem is somewhere on your end. Setting the file to read-only might help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check if our access to the file is corrupting it.

Comment: you can copy (select null) to ..hba', but copy would replace NULL to \N, or if you copy in binary format, it would look like `PGCOPY▒`

Comment: @NickBarnes you were right, the file was modified by ourself and the File.WriteAllText did not correctly dispose. When shutting down the PC shortly after the modification the file was corrupted